# Can I make a socket created in node.js blocking after passing the file handle to a child process?

Tags: node.js, sockets, fork, nonblocking, file-descriptor

I'm `spawn`ing a `child_process`, and am passing a listening socket created in the parent process along to that new child process as fd 3 after STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR.

The child process, which is not implemented using node.js, `listen`s on that socket for HTTP connections from its parent process, and the parent process doesn't directly use the socket it previously created.

Node naturally created the socket to be non-blocking, but the child process requires it to be blocking, and clearing the `O_NONBLOCK` bit with `fcntl` from the child process appears to result in the behaviour I'm expecting.

Is this approach fair game for this use-case, or are there scenarios in which the node.js parent process might still attempt to perform a potentially blocking operation on the socket it created, which presumably would violate the run-time's expectations and block the main-loop?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, once you've passed the socket to the client, the parent nodejs no longer keeps track of the socket or ever does anything with it, so unless your own code in the parent attempts to do something with the socket, you should be fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you. I'm not loving the "should be" part. Is there anything I could perhaps do to verify this other than reading the implementation and convincing myself based on that? I'd also happily accept your current comment as an answer if you were to post it as such.

Comment: First off, there is  this line in the doc: ***The parent cannot track when the socket is destroyed.*** which implies the parent loses access to the socket.  Beyond that, I'd say you have two options here.  1) You can delve into the code involved in sending a socket and attempt to fully understand exactly what it is doing on all platforms you expect to run on.  2) You can figure out what bad consequence you are afraid of, devise a test for that and see if your parent is affected by that scenario in any way.  In other words, code review or test or both.

Comment: I think the question that's actually being asked here is "do the NodeJS developers consider it an internal implementation detail that this works, or part of the API contract?" Or equivalently, "would they consider it a semver-major change if they ever made this stop working?"

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yeah, I think that's a good rephrasing. I prefer your first version as it doesn't imply that it does in fact currently work reliably currently.